# Second Custom Cell in TableView Controller Generates Error

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell

I have a UITableViewController in which I use more than one custom cell.  I have used multiple custom cells in the past with no problem, and I am using the same strategy to implement them as I have in the past so this error baffles me.  First, some code:

This is how I register the custom cells in viewDidLoad:

```
    // Registering the custom cell
    let nib1 = UINib(nibName: "OmniCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib1, forCellReuseIdentifier: "omniCell")

    let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "RankCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "rankCell")
```

This is how I create them in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    let cell1: OmniCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("omniCell") as! OmniCell
    let cell2: RankCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rankCell") as! RankCell
```

when I comment out the code related to the second custom cell the program runs fine, but when both custom cells are used I get this error:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key rankCell.
```

Both custom cells are implemented in an identical manner so I am not sure why the second custom cell generates this error while the first one does not.  What am I missing?

Update:  Upon request I am sharing the entire cellforrowatindexpath func:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // This line works:
    let cell1: OmniCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("omniCell") as! OmniCell

    // It is this line that breaks if not commented out:
    let cell2: RankCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rankCell") as! RankCell

    // This line works:
    let cell3: ProgressCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("progressCell") as! ProgressCell


    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return cell1
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return cell2
    } else {
        return cell3
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you just check whether have you given any different identifier for the rankCell in the XIB ?? I mean, go to attribute inspector in the rankCell.XIB and check what is the identifier that you've given.If it is not "rankCell" then could you change it to "rankCell" and try to build.

Comment: Please share your code in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @iamyogish Thank you for the suggestion.  I made sure the identifier in the Attribute Inspector was rankCell and this did not help.  None of the other custom cells have the identifier in the XIB either.

Comment: @Kavya  I have included the entire function in the question text above. I hope this helps shed some light.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this.  The problem was that there was an errant connection in the XIB.  Refer to this picture:

[image]

There was an additional "broken" outlet above the one good one that was like:
   rankCell  --->  Rank Cell
But instead of a filled in circle it had what appeared to be an elongated symbol that was too small to make out.  I removed the outlet and the app built and ran normally.  I am not sure where that connection came from, none of the other custom cells had one like it.